# Firebase Storage Image Not Downloading in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage Image Not Downloading in Tableview. If I replace the line let tempImageRef = storage.child("myFiles/sample.jpg"), it's showing the single image. But if try to grab all the images inside 'myFiles' , it doesn't work. Please help

```
func fetchPhotos()
    {
        //let database = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://fir-test-bafca.appspot.com")
        let tempImageRef = storage.child("myFiles/")

        tempImageRef.data(withMaxSize: (1*1024*1024)) { (data, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
            }else{
                print(data!)

                let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.picArray.append(pic!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post you `UITableViewDataSource` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing an entire folder (`myFiles/`). That wont work. You need to reference each image individually.

One way to do this is to write the image metadata to your realtime database when you upload an image. Then read the metadata (more specifically the path) and then reference the image that way.

If you have 3 images you want to upload and store, you could write the metadata as follows:

```
/images
  /image1key
    /metdata
      /path
  /image2key
    /metdata
     /path
  /image3key
    /metdata
      /path
```

Then you can query your database for your images path's like so

```
let ref = Firebase.database().ref("images")
ref.observe(.value, withCompletion: { snapshot in
  if let values = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
    if let metadata = values["metadata"] as? [String: Any] {
      let imagePath = metadata["path"]
      //Now download your image from storage.
    }
  }
})
```

This isn't the cleanest code and you can definitely improve, but it will work :)

Comment: As an addendum; The structure could be simplified by just storing the paths as key: value pairs like /images/image1key: image1Path and /images/image2key: image2path. That would simplify the code considerably. But... If the OP wants to store more than just the path to the image (perhaps a image name or other data), your setup is the right solution.

Comment: Yes, i've done so & it's working fine.Firstly i added those photos in Firebase Storage & then added those photos 'download link' in a node of Firebase Database.After that i can easily retrieve those photos in tableview.
Thanks a lot...